# Writing NSPrintForDebugger in GDB to print objects in C

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

When using GDB (using text interface, TTY, and SSH on Gentoo Linux) for debugging C code, I want to print the data in objects. When I try using `print-object <objectname>`, I get the message

> evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function "_NSPrintForDebugger"

I can't find any documentation or examples (is it me, or is Linux documentation very short on examples?) of how to create such a function. *I would like an example(s) of NSPrintForDebugger functions for gdb that I can model.* Note that I am new to C, Linux, MPI, emacs, and gdb.

To make this a little more difficult, I can't find the definition of all the objects I want to print.

If it helps make an example, some of the objects I'd like to `print-object` are:

1. UserData

   typedef struct {
     realtype dx, hdcoef, hacoef;
     int npes, my_pe
     MPI_Comm comm;
     realtype z[100];
   } *UserData;
   UserData data;
2. N_Vector (part of SUNDIALS, may have [varying definitions](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/kin_guide/node7.html)).
3. void *cvode_mem (any pointer to void)
4. realtype (floats of varying size, also part of SUNDIALS)
5. MPI_Comm (which might be just an integer)

P.S. I have noticed that, for instance, `p *data` displays a lot of information. But I want more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSPrintForDebugger` function that the GDB `print-object` command is calling is part of the Objective-C runtime. Since you aren't using Objective-C, ignore it.

Comment: Then how do I print an object?

Comment: What you're already doing (`p *data`) is about the best you'll get without writing a bunch of custom functions and/or GDB macros.

Comment: Just so you know, I spent hours forming that question to make sure I had the relevant information in it and asked it clearly and searched over and over to make sure I didn't miss anything important on the web. And you answered it within one hour and one sentence. (And I have so many questions!). :D